# Ошибка при попытке загрузить изображение из Галереи

Tags: android, изображения

Добрый день! 
Пытаюсь загрузить изображение из галереи, но получаю следующую ошибку:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{2e0bed9b 8379:com.example.eugen.businesscard/u0a81} (pid=8379, uid=10081) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

Вот код, который выкидывает исключение:

```
try {
        Uri bufUri = Uri.parse(pic_uri);
        final InputStream imageStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(bufUri);
        image_source = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Мой Manifest файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>
```

При этом, при первом запуске приложения и смене "аватара", изображение меняется на выбранное, но после сохранения и перезапуска - появляется эта ошибка. Т.е. проблема явно при обращении по Uri который берется из Базы данных. Сохранение и обращение Uri делаю так:

mUri.toString(); - на сохранении.
Uri.parce(mUri); - на вытягивании из БД.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с чтением uri после сохранения в БД, почему вы не пишите об этом?Как вы uri в бд сохраняете? Оформите вопрос в соответсвии с вашей действительной проблемой

Comment: Uri сохраняю: mUri.toString() , когда забираю из БД делаю: Uri.parse(pic_uri);

Comment: @Eugen вы решили проблему? у меня есть вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
Permission Denial
requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

Тебе прямым текстом написано что случилось и что нужно делать.

Comment: В Manifest файле все права добавлены:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

Comment: Файл в студию было бы неплохо.

Comment: Это все Permission-ы из него. Или вы о целом файле с кодом?

Comment: Пробел после READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, по аналогии с остальными пунктами. Ошибка именно в манифесте, а не в коде. Для форматирования кода используйте 4 пробела. Так читабельность будет в разы выше.

Comment: К сожалению пробелы не помогли(

Comment: Остальные разрешения работают? Manifest парсится корректно?

Comment: Да, остальное всё работает.

Comment: Тестируешь на KitKat?

Comment: Нет, версия SDK 22.

Comment: @Eugen, расскажите как вы решили проблему, сам столкнулся с такой же ситуацией.

Answer (score 0):

*Я согласен с rvoid проблема в манифесте  а IDE при редактировании не выделяет неправильный код ? там всё таки проблема с пробелами ...*

Comment: А остальные разрешения работают ?

Comment: Да, остальное всё работает

Comment: Делаю в Android Studio, никаких проблем в Манифесте она не показала... я изменил уже, согласно советов, но не помогло. Сверху добавил содержимое манифеста.

Comment: а вы пробовали убрать эту строку <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" /> ?

Comment: Пробовал и убирать и переставлять. ошибка та же самая.

Comment: Вот ссылка **http://learn-android.ru/news/vybiraem_izobrazhenie_iz_galerei_s_pomoshhju_intent_action_pick/2015-04-19-95.html** может поможет ....

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Но тут ситуация какая:  1) сперва у меня в приложении есть окошко, я нажимаю - выбираю картинку из галереи (всё работает) и ставлю как "аватар". 2) После этого сохраняю uri.toString() в Базу данных свою. 3) после перезапуска приложения, оно берет из базы uri и должно подгрузить картинку , но вот.. на этом моменте и происходит краш.

Comment: Потом изображение где хранится ? короче надо другое разрешение....

Comment: Я храню только uri изображения и каждый раз при загрузке приложения - получаю картинку по этому uri, а само изображение остается в галерее, на устройстве (использую для теста AVD)

Comment: Вот ещё ссылочка **https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions** помоему по теме

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения проблемы можно использовать SharedPreferences, если для пользователя используется изображение только для аватара. Сохранили локально(разрешения никакие не требуются), затем вытащили и отобразили с любой графической библиотекой.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте как правильно запрашивать пермишины начиная с 6го андроида.

```
    final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };
    ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
        String[] tmp = new String[permissions.size()];
        permissions.toArray(tmp);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, tmp, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    } else {
        onPermissionsGranted();
    }
```